# Change verbose_name for external apps in virtualennv

Tags: django

I have installed django-celery app in virtualenv and I want to change the label of this app to display the meaningful label on breadcrumbs navbar. I'm not able to find any solution to this problem. Can anybody help me to rename the label of app installed in virtual environment?
I have chnaged the label of internal apps using verbose_name in the following code:

***Apps.py***

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EmailEngineConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'email_engine'
    verbose_name = 'Email Engine'
```

How to perform the same task for external apps?

Comment: Which version of Celery are you using? If you are using Celery 3.1+, then you shouldn't need to install django-celery, because [support for Django is built in](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#first-steps-with-django).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `AppConfig` class for any app, it doesn't matter whether it is external or not.

If the external app already has an `AppConfig` class, then you may wish to subclass this.

```
from external_app.apps import ExternalAppConfig

class MyExternalAppConfig(ExternalAppConfig):
    ...
```

Then replace the existing entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` with `'path.to.apps.MyExternalAppConfig`.

See the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#for-application-users) for more info.

Comment: djcelery app doesnot seam to have apps.py file. where should I create this file ?

Comment: You can create the `AppConfig` class wherever you like in your project. The example in the docs suggests creating an `apps.py` in the inner project folder (the one that contains `settings.py`).

Comment: `from django.apps import AppConfig


class DjceleryConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'djcelery'
    verbose_name = 'Scheduler'
`
Here is the code I added into my apps.py 
now I'm confused how to link this apps.py file to djcelery app.

Comment: I added it into INSTALLED_APPS like: '<project_name>.apps.DjceleryConfig' but now it can not register the models of djcelery app.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then. Hope you manage to get it working.

Comment: I removed the manual registration of the models with admin. Its working now. Thanks a lot.